# Delete a specific file from past commit from a branch

Tags: file, branch, git-commit

I've read many solutions but I am looking for the method like this:
I have the commits: A, B, C, D, E.... W.
I'd like to delete a specific file: filename.json from the commit H from the branch not from the repo.

Git advice me to use Git Filter, but it didn't work for me.

I checkouted to that H commit and
I used a command "rm filename.json" It says something like that rm cannot find the path .... because it doesn't exists.

I checkout to the latest commit and I used a command: git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm.--cached --ignore-unmatch filename.json' HEAD
But it starts to scan a whole repo instead of the current brach.
Thanks